# SQL Returning todays data only

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to return data (todays) from my table.  I'm using this query which does the job but not as fast as I would like.

Current query

```
WHERE (CallDetail.DNIS='456456') AND CallDetail.ConnectedDateTimeGmt > CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT))AS DATETIME)
```

Another query that I use returns the past weeks worth of data in a matter of seconds.

```
WHERE (CallDetail.LocalName='Name') AND (CallDetail.ConnectedDate Between DATEADD(wk,-1,GetDate()) And GetDate())
```

Is there a more effective query I can use to return only data for today?

Comment: is the date datatype available to you?

Comment: Your two queries are not equivalent.  One is comparingon DNIS and the other on LocalNames.  I wouldn't be surprised if you had an index on LocalName that is speeding up the second query.  And the date comparison is on different fields.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting two times to return date part from GETDATE() which slows down query

```
WHERE (CallDetail.DNIS='456456') 
AND CallDetail.ConnectedDateTimeGmt > CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT))AS DATETIME)
```

use a faster way to return only the date part from GETDATE()

```
WHERE (CallDetail.DNIS='456456')
AND CallDetail.ConnectedDateTimeGmt > DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up the query, then think about indexes.  For this query, the most effective index would be on `CallDetail(DNIS, ConnectedDateTimeGmt)`.

Your second query is probably running faster because you have an index on either `CallDetail(ConnectedDate)` or `CallDetail(LocalName)`.

Kudos for only doing the date arithmetic on `getdate()` rather than on the field name (this can impede the use of indexes).  If you are using a more recent version of SQL Server, then the most readable approach is `cast(getdate() as date)` for the conversion.  However, the way to speed up the query is by judicious use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You use a cross join to the date to calculate this only once, not sure how this would affect your performance but I've used this in the past and it always seemed to hit the indexes.

```
SELECT *

FROM [MyData]
CROSS JOIN (DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) AS CURRDATE) XJOIN

WHERE (CallDetail.DNIS='456456')
AND CallDetail.ConnectedDateTimeGmt > XJOIN.CURRDATE
```